# Why is there no Python text highlighting in my Atom Text editor?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have just installed atom and am trying to run some python code. I have manually selected that I am using python in the bottom right corner to be sure and yet there is still zero text highlighting. The text highlighting is working in other languages(I tried HTML and it worked perfectly). The file is saved with a .py extension. I am very new to coding so feel free to assume I'm missing something Blatant. Atom-ide-ui and ide-python are installed. [Here's a screenshot of editor as I see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGY1M.png).

Comment: You'll need to provide more details or a screenshot to show this happening.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend installing the [ide-python package](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python) in Atom.  You can run this from the command line:

```
apm install atom-ide-ui
apm install ide-python
```

Or install `ide-python` and `atom-ide-ui` from Install in Atom's settings.